# Total Variation and geodesic Curvature

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, geodesic

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a smooth curve, then is there are relationship between the total variation of $f$ and the geodesic curvature of $f$?

I expect they both should be zero iff $f$ is a line but how to make this clear?

Comment: No, the total variation of a function $f$ is $0$ if only if the function is constant. Intuitively, total variation is about $\|f'\|$ and curvature is about $\|f''\|$, so I don't know what you're looking for or expecting.

Comment: So the total variation of the derivative is 0 if and only if the curvature is zero?

Comment: Assuming a constant-speed parametrization, yes.

Comment: How would the formal proof of this look?

Comment: Could you define "variation"?